# Change chart range based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

Question on dynamic range selection for chart of excel. Hope someone can help me out.

I have a tabular data in excel sheet from B27:F41. This data will expand and contract on both sides ie rows and even columns will increase/ decrease.

Q1.My biggest table will be B27:CZ120. Is it possible I give the biggest range and chart will ignore all empty rows and columns? or atleast empty columns.

Q2. If above is not possible then how can I change the range from a macro.

Reg. question 2 - Consider that in macro I already know the range for which data is present. I just want to pass this range to CHART RANGE.

Found some explanation [here](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/10/15/dynamic-chart-data-series/) but it is only for dynamic number of rows and not columns.

Let me know in case more information is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution from your link is pretty nice: do adopt it for columns you only need to swap `OFFSET` arguments and use calculation for the range height.

Here's my own sample book I use for teaching new stuff, it includes 3 samples - rows, columns and stacked columns: https://www.dropbox.com/s/76llm0na9tvee90/DynamicCharts.xlsx

Sure you'll be able to easily adopt it for your needs. Good luck!

Comment: Excellent work..+1 for sharing the excel sheet publicly...but could you tell me how you have achieved this. I am interested in the stacked bars but when I right click on the chart and go to chart data it just shows me what range is currently selected.

Comment: @antnewbee You're welcome, use it as you wish) To adopt charts for your needs, go to Ribbon `Formulas` > `Name Manager`, then select each region, it will be highlighted. You need to correct `OFFSET` parts.

Comment: In chart3 if I add one more row eg severity:none then it is not reflected in the chart. What I have done is I have created a named range as you said and I have given that named range in "chart data range". It is working but when I add delete the rows/columns then the chart is not updated automatically, I have to go to chart data range and give the named region again..

Comment: @antnewbee could you please share the file - it's impossible to solve your issues without seeing actual data?